# Implementation of "Global Contrast Factor" in Python with OpenCV and Numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I would like to implement the procedure detailed in the paper *Global Contrast Factor - a New Approach to Image Contrast* by Krešimir Matkovic, László Neumann, Attila Neumann, Thomas Psik, and Werner Purgathofer in Python using Numpy and OpenCV.  However, there is one step I'm struggling with.

The procedure essentially involves some basic multiplication and addition over the pixels of a grayscale image, which can be done fairly easily with Numpy vectorized operations.  However, this procedure needs to be repeated for the image at smaller and smaller resolutions, **where the superpixels in the smaller images are combined according to a particular formula provided in the paper.**

Starting from the original image, each time the dimensions are halved, and "the superpixel value is computed as average linear luminance, and
this is then converted to perceptual luminance," given by the formulas:

[image]

where gamma = 2.2 and k is the original pixel value [0, 255].  I assume this means that each time I scale down the image, I need to compute the first formula for four pixels at a time (arranged in a square), average them, and then apply the second formula to use as the grayscale value for the smaller image.

My problem is that I'm not sure how I can efficiently scale an image down so that its pixel values are calculated in a way that corresponds to those formulas.  OpenCV already has some built in resizing algorithms, but I'm honestly not sure which, if any, would provide a similar result to the one detailed in the paper.

**How can you efficiently resize a grayscale image where the pixel values in the smaller image are determined by those formulas?**

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV `resize` does not perform these operations. You will have to explicitly calculate the linear luminance values for each pixel in the image and then apply `resize` with linear interpolation (`INTER_LINEAR`). Linear interpolation will calculate the average. See the following example. It calculates the average of non-overlapping 2x2 blocks.

```
>>> im = np.random.randint(0, 255, (8, 8)).astype(np.float32)
>>> im
array([[ 74.,  73., 109.,  41., 165.,  24., 165., 189.],
       [143.,  15., 212., 139.,  63., 123., 222., 231.],
       [ 58., 150., 168., 234.,  64., 139., 239., 179.],
       [227.,  11., 142.,  42.,  28., 127., 213.,  52.],
       [187., 232.,  26.,  34.,  63., 104., 197., 155.],
       [ 95., 154.,  69.,  56., 163.,  93.,  37., 136.],
       [ 14., 249., 204.,  15., 182., 226.,  20., 114.],
       [231.,  61., 155., 184., 211., 162.,  62.,  26.]], dtype=float32)
>>> cv2.resize(im, dsize=None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
array([[ 76.25, 125.25,  93.75, 201.75],
       [111.5 , 146.5 ,  89.5 , 170.75],
       [167.  ,  46.25, 105.75, 131.25],
       [138.75, 139.5 , 195.25,  55.5 ]], dtype=float32)
>>> (168+234+142+42)/4
146.5
```

As I understood, you calculate the linear luminance (*l*) only for the original image, and then successively reduce the resolution (please correct me if I'm wrong).

You can speedup the linear luminance calculation using a lookup table (LUT) because there will only be a maximum of 256 different pixel values if your image is 8-bit (8U).

Comment: That's a good idea, but remember that in the smaller image, the pixel value is computed as the average of that value in pixel blocks of four (since both dimensions get halved at every step).  So how would I be able to compute that average quickly since it depends on where the pixels are?

Comment: @jippyjoe4 Linear interpolation will calculate the average. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the GCF measure based on the original paper for anyone in need of this.

Note that the weights-producing function may not be ideal for different resolutions than was experimented with in the paper.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.measure
import cv2

class GlobalContrastFactorContrastMeasure:
    """
    Global Contrast Factor is a global measure of the overall image contrast
    as perceived by the HVS.

    It is calculated as a weighted average of the local contrast computed
    at different resolution levels.

    See:
    Original paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Werner-Purgathofer-2/publication/220795239_Global_Contrast_Factor_-_a_New_Approach_to_Image_Contrast/links/0912f506162e773787000000/Global-Contrast-Factor-a-New-Approach-to-Image-Contrast.pdf
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.gamma = 2.2

    def assess(self, img: np.ndarray):
        # Use Value from HSV, which represents the perceived brightness
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[..., -1]

        l = self._correct_lumuninance_with_gamma(img)
        C = [self._calculate_average_contrast(l)]

        li = l
        num_resolution_decreases = self._get_num_resolution_decreases(img)
        for i in range(num_resolution_decreases):
            # Decrease resolution of l by half using average pooling 2x2
            li = self._average_pooling(li)
            # Calculate the average contrast
            Ci = self._calculate_average_contrast(li)
            C.append(Ci)

        weights = self._calculate_weights(len(C))
        gcf = np.sum(weights * C)
        return gcf

    def _correct_lumuninance_with_gamma(self, img: np.ndarray):
        return np.power(img / 255, self.gamma)

    def _get_num_resolution_decreases(self, img: np.ndarray):
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        # Average pooling uses 2x2 kernel -> use log2
        # Do not decrease the resolution below 3 pixels in size
        min_resolution_pixels = 3
        min_resolution_log = np.log2(min_resolution_pixels)
        h_resolutions = int(np.log2(height) - min_resolution_log)
        w_resolutions = int(np.log2(width) - min_resolution_log)
        num_resolution_decreases = min(h_resolutions, w_resolutions)
        return num_resolution_decreases

    def _average_pooling(self, l: np.ndarray):
        return skimage.measure.block_reduce(l, (2, 2), np.mean)

    def _calculate_average_contrast(self, l: np.ndarray):
        # perceptual luminance
        eps = 0.0001  # for numerical stability
        L = 100 * np.sqrt(l + eps)

        # local contrast as the avarage of the four neigboring pixels of perceptual luminance
        lc = self._average_difference(L)

        # average contrast
        C = np.mean(lc)
        return C

    def _average_difference(self, image):
        """
        Calculates the average difference of a pixel and its neighbors.
        """
        # Pad the array with zeros to handle boundary cases
        padded_image = np.pad(image, ((1, 1), (1, 1)), mode='edge')

        # Calculate the differences between each pixel and its four neighbors
        differences = np.abs(image - padded_image[:-2, 1:-1])  # Top neighbor
        differences += np.abs(image - padded_image[2:, 1:-1])  # Bottom neighbor
        differences += np.abs(image - padded_image[1:-1, :-2])  # Left neighbor
        differences += np.abs(image - padded_image[1:-1, 2:])  # Right neighbor

        # Count the number of valid neighbors for each pixel
        # Eges have only three neighbors and corners just two.
        valid_neighbors = np.zeros_like(image)
        valid_neighbors[:-1, :] += 1  # Top neighbor
        valid_neighbors[1:, :] += 1  # Bottom neighbor
        valid_neighbors[:, :-1] += 1  # Left neighbor
        valid_neighbors[:, 1:] += 1  # Right neighbor

        # Calculate the average difference for each pixel
        average_diff = differences / valid_neighbors

        return average_diff

    def _calculate_weights(self, num_resolutions):
        """
        Calculates weights using a function proposed in the paper.

        Note that this function was determined in the original paper for a specific resolution
        of images, which may not be correct for different resolutions.
        """
        i = np.arange(num_resolutions)
        weights = (-0.406385 * i / num_resolutions + 0.334573) * i / num_resolutions + 0.0877526
        return weights
```